# elegant way to write a function

Tags: r, function

What is a more elegant way to write the below function. I am trying to practice my function development skills, and I am simply trying to manually recreate the CIs of a linear model. I am very well aware of the confint(model) function, but still...

```
jad<-function(x, y) {
  model<-lm(y~x)
  std.err<-coef(summary(model))[, 2]
  coef.model1<-coef(summary(model))[, 1]
  upper.ci<-coef.model1+1.96*std.err
  lower.ci<-coef.model1-1.96*std.err
  print(upper.ci)
  print(lower.ci)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the code below?

```
jad <- function(x, y) {
  `colnames<-`(
    coef(summary(lm(y ~ x)))[,1:2] %*% matrix(c(1, 1.96, 1, -1.96), nrow = 2),
    c("upper.ci", "lower.ci")
  )
}
```

Comment: Error in coef(summary(lm(y ~ x))) %*% matrix(c(1, 1.96, 1, -1.96), nrow = 2) : 
  non-conformable arguments

Comment: @KEA What is the dimension of `coef(summary(lm(y ~ x)))`? could you show it in the post?

Comment: it's a 2x4, 2 rows (intercept and slope) and 4 columns(estimate, std.error, t-value and p-value)

Comment: Estimate    Std. Error        t value                Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 30.569915  2.8709642     10.647961          1.564139e-22
stai            0.177085    0.1031589      1.716623           8.712701e-02

Comment: @KEA Okey, see my update and have a try again.

Comment: Perfect!!! how intuitive! Thank you!